# how to implement flatten for stream using flatmap

Tags: scala

How do I implement flatten for Stream using flatmap? For function to preserve content of input stream, but simplifies its structure into a single stream?

```
def flatten(ffa: Stream[Stream[A]]): 
    Stream[A]=
```

Comment: Is is some assignment?

Comment: its from chapter 5 of manning functional, i am a beginner and studying my own

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```scala
def flatten[A](ffa: Stream[Stream[A]]): Stream[A] = ffa.flatMap(identity)

>flatten(Stream(Stream(1,2,3), Stream(4,5,6), Stream(7,8,9)))
// res1: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```